# trying to put an 'led' <div> into a navbar as an icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have a functional style that produces an led indicator that suits my needs.
CSS:

```
.led-yellow {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #FF0;
    box-shadow: #000 0 -1px 6px 1px, inset #660 0 -1px 8px, #FF0 0 3px 11px;
}
```

If I put (html) `<div class="led-yellow"></div>`, I get a nice-looking yellow led. I would like to put this in a partially-collapsible sidebar. I can get it to do what I want when collapsed, but it always ends up on a separate line from the label when expanded.
[image: collapsed = good]
[image: expanded = ugly]
[image: goal = expanded in-line]

The sidebar html is as follows:

```
<section class="sidebar">
    <ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
...
       <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>Documentation</span></a></li> <!-- works! -->
   </ul>
   <ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
       <li><a href="#" disabled><div class="led led-yellow" style="margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt; margin-left: 0pt; margin-right: 10pt"></div><span>Something else</span></a></li>
   </ul>
</section>
```

My apologies if I have left something necessary out, or if I've given far too much detail when what I need is actually really simple.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. could you please add a [working demo or code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block;` to **led-yellow**

```
.led-yellow {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #FF0;
    box-shadow: #000 0 -1px 6px 1px, inset #660 0 -1px 8px, #FF0 0 3px 11px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much.